# MessageSecurityException in response to WS web service

Tags: java, c#, web-services, soap, ws-security

I am writing a client that makes a POST call to an external web service which is configured for WS-Security, I have pulled in the reference from the WSDL provided, the `customBinding` is below:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="OOH_ServiceSoap12Binding">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8"/>
            <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" 
                enableUnsecuredResponse="true" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false" includeTimestamp="true" defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default">
        </security>
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I am loading the certificates from file as below:

```
var fiClientCert = new FileInfo("cpmsws.ic24.nhs.uk.pfx");
var clientCertBytes = new byte[fiClientCert.Length];
fiClientCert.OpenRead().Read(clientCertBytes, 0, clientCertBytes.Length);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(clientCertBytes, "P@ssw0rd");
cert.Verify();
service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

var fiServiceCert = new FileInfo("Rhapsody_Server_Key.cer");
var serviceCertBytes = new byte[fiServiceCert.Length];
fiServiceCert.OpenRead().Read(serviceCertBytes, 0, serviceCertBytes.Length);
var serviceCert = new X509Certificate2(serviceCertBytes, string.Empty);
serviceCert.Verify();
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = serviceCert;
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate
    .Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate
    .Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

var address = service.Endpoint.Address;
service.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(address.Uri,
    new DnsEndpointIdentity("Rhapsody Server Key"), address.Headers, 
    address.GetReaderAtMetadata(),
    address.GetReaderAtExtensions());

service.episodeOutcome("TEST123", 9448969759, "Other", "", "Test", "12345", "12345", 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15), DateTime.Now, "Test", "TEST", new DateTime(1970, 01, 01), 
    "Male", "Test", "", "", "", "", "TN24 0GP", "G8000", out description);
```

The above code works and I can see in Fiddler the message being sent and the service is returning a `HTTP 200` response with the response XML, however I get the following exception in my test application

```
Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
Message: The primary signature must be encrypted
```

Like I said I can see the raw xml in Fiddler so I know that the SOAP message is correct and is being processed by the service, the response is being sent back but the exception above is getting thrown.

I have googled but everything I have found relates to WCF but the service I am calling is in Java and therefore not WCF related.

Can anyone please shed any light on why I am getting this exception and how to deal with this?